# Displaying multiple curves (SOR method)

Tags: python, numpy, math

Here's is my code implementing the SOR(Successive over-relaxation) method.
I would like to display a graph with several curves representing the values of the norm 2 of ||r^k||, the residue, in fonction of the parameter "omega".
I have a problem with displaying multiple curves on the same graph. 
Could you tell me what's wrong with my program?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def SOR(A,b,Imax,eps,x0,omega):
    D=np.diag(np.diag(A))
    M=np.dot((1/omega),D)+np.tril(A,-1)
    N=M-A
    r=np.dot(A,x0)-b
    x=x0
    i=0
    err=1+eps
    res=[]
    while((i<Imax) and ((la.norm(r))>=eps)):
        x=np.dot(np.dot((la.inv(M)),N),x)+np.dot((la.inv(M)),b)
        r=np.dot(A,x)-b
        err = la.norm(r,2)
        res.append(err)
        i=i+1
    return (x,i,res)


A=np.array([[2,0,0],[4,5,0],[7,8,9]])
x0=np.array([[4],[8],[7]])   
b=np.array([[20],[8],[7]])
```

Here's our graph function, which displays only one curve.

```
def Graph():
i=0.1
while(i<=2):
    [x,i,res]=SOR(A,b,100,10**(-3),x0,i)
    plt.plot(range(len(res)),res)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()
    i=i+0.1

Graph()
```

Comment: Have you tried to move `plt.show()` out of the `while` loop? `matplotlib` has problems with the interactive mode on some systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried it but the graph displays still one sole curve

Comment: if you add a `print(i)` to the end of your `Graph()` function, you can see the value is 100 after a one iteration. So it breaks your while loop and  therefore, only a one plot is drawn.

Comment: I don't understand why i equal's to 100 after one iteration... :/

Comment: Well, it counts in `SOR` up to 100 and you change `i`, giving this back to `[x,i,res]`. If you change it to `[x,j,res]` to prevent that `i` is overwritten and move `plt.show` out of the while loop, you get a diagram with an overlay of 19 curves. If this is, what you intended to do, is another matter.